# Create Array From String With Spesific Length

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an string like this

```
$str = "ABCD123456EFGH91";
```

and I want an array with 12 digits value that taken from string like:

```
Array (
    [0] => ABCD123456EF 
    [1] => BCD123456EFG
    [2] => CD123456EFGH
    [3] => D123456EFGH9
    [4] => 123456EFGH91
)
```

I am a newbie in PHP. How to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using substr()

```
<?php

$str = "ABCD123456EFGH91";

$i = 0;
$arr = [];
while (1) {
    $sub_str = substr($str, $i++, 12);
    if (strlen($sub_str) !== 12) {
        break;
    }
    $arr[] = $sub_str;
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str                = "ABCD123456EFGH91"; // String you want your elements to be build with.
$numberOfElements   = 5; // Number of elements you are planning (input number)
$counter            = 0; // Just a counter variable.
$arrayObject        = array(); // Empty Array to store outcome
while($counter < $numberOfElements)
{
    $arrayObject[$counter] = substr(str_shuffle($str), 0, 12);
    $counter++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayObject);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

This will work fair enough.

```
substr(String,start,end);
```

It will help to get Sub-String out of any String variable. Provide the start and end number to get started.

```
str_shuffle(String);
```

This Function will help to get a shuffled String out of the given string. As we needed the string to be containing the characters of given string, we can use the combination of this two functions to work the problem out.

Let me know if you need help with anything such as this one.